# intelligencia.urlrewriter: bad request error

Tags: url-rewriting, clean-urls

I want to implement url rewriting with intelligencia.urlrewriter.problem is when clean URL Contains special characters such as % : * & and more.in this case I get a bad request,because the cleaned url does not contain ? sign. I work with .net 3.5 . 
Is there a solution for this problem?

thanks friends

Comment: there is no solution for this problem?please help...